# Fieldgroup inside of a table form

Tags: html, forms, html-table

```html
<fieldset style="width: 400px;">
        <legend><h2>Form Validation</h2></legend>
    <form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="ime"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Username</TD>
                <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="send">
    </form>
</fieldset>
```

I am currently making a form inside of a table... This is kind of new for me, since I don't know how to do it. Above is the code I have tried, and I need something like this.

[image: This is what i need]

If someone could get me on the right path, ill be really grateful.

**Note:** As you can see in the picture above, it needs to have `colspan` of 3, so they can all have equal width. I made a perfect one with just `<form>`, but i just found out we have to do it inside of a table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is `colgroup` - there you can specify, how much of space of the table any column should take.
For your example it would be something like this: (plz note that I didn't feel all of needed rows)

```html
<fieldset style="width: 400px;">
        <legend><h2>Form Validation</h2></legend>
    <form>
        <table>
        <colgroup>
        <col width="40%"/>
        <col width="60%"/>
        </colgroup>
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="ime"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Username:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Re-type password:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Gender:</td>
                <td>
                <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" />
                <label for="male">Male</label>
                <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" />
                <label for="female">Female</label>
                <input type="radio" id="other" name="gender" />
                <label for="other">Other</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Programming skills:</td>
                <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="java"/>
                <label for="java">Java</label>
                 <input type="checkbox" id="ruby"/>
                <label for="ruby">Ruby</label>
                 <input type="checkbox" id="net"/>
                <label for="net">.Net</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="send">
    </form>
</fieldset>
```